# Fixed positioned div disappearing in ie7

Tags: internet-explorer-7, css-position

I'm having a problem with my website: [here](http://www.chillifish.com). The div #header doesn't show in ie7.

For various reasons, the site's been in development for 18 months and at some point previously, it must have had the same issue and I fixed it, hence the empty div with the ie7 hack comment. However, I've obviously changed something that's affected it, but can't work out what's happening.

The only thing I can remember changing is the order of some of the floats.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fixed positioning was a red herring. It was because the #top div had a z-index of 1, which for some reason put it above the #header div with a z-index of 999. Removing z-index from the #top div has solved it. Seems like ie7 has issues with z-index.